# Calculate median based on counts of value

Tags: r, median

I have a following data frame:

```
   numbers Freq
1        4    2
2        5    1
3       23    2
4       34    2
```

I know how to calculate median in r when frequency is 1 (`` median(`numbers`, na.rm = TRUE) ``), but how to do that when frequency is different from 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a logical index with `!=`, use that to subset the 'numbers' column and get the `median`

```
with(df1, median(numbers[Freq != 1], na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 23
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(numbers = c(4L, 5L, 23L, 34L), Freq = c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `tapply` along with `subset`

```
> with(subset(df,Freq != 1),tapply(numbers,Freq,median,na.rm = TRUE))
 2
23
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(numbers = c(4L, 5L, 23L, 34L), Freq = c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3",
"4"))
```